# MongoMapper ALL vs. WHERE difference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper

I stumbled across this randomly in my code:

When I write a query using MongoMapper in Rails like this:

@res = Customer.**where**({$foo, $bar})

And then I run @res.inspect - I get:

```
@res is #<MongoMapper::Plugins::Querying::DecoratedPluckyQuery merchant_id: "518b762e89651a0389000013", phone: "**********", transformer: #<Proc:0x007fde074078a0@/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongo_mapper-0.13.0.beta1/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb:66 (lambda)>>
```

Ergo - my variable is the actual query string.

When I change it like this:

@res = Customer.**all**({$foo, $bar})

And then @res.inspect - I get:

```
@res is [#<Customer _id: BSON::ObjectId('51a9806589651a05da000001'), account_id: "", admin_id: nil, city_id: "Kailua, Hawaii", company_id: "0", created_at: Sat, 11 May 2013 00:00:00 UTC +00:00, cust_notes: "", datecreated: 2013-01-06 00:00:00 UTC, datemodified: 2013-01-06 00:00:00 UTC, **REMOVED PRIVATE DATA HERE** type: "customer", updated_at: Sun, 15 Sep 2013 22:43:56 UTC +00:00, zip_code: *****>]
```

Ergo - it's actually the *result* of the query (which is what I always expect).

Now weirdly, the specific difference here is that I'm NOT doing a "respond_to do |format|" and I'm not accessing @res in a view - I'm trying to look at it's results *still in the controller* for a redirect purpose.

Because *absolutely everywhere else* in my application I'm doing this same "Customer.where" or "Job.where" stuff and then that instance variable is being tossed up to the view and I'll do something like @customer.name or whatever to get the value out of the array.

FOR WHY

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is a few months old but I thought I'd respond in case anyone else stumbles across it with the same question.

WHERE returns a Plucky::Query rather than the results, so that you can add extra features on to it before the actual query is performed.

```
@johns = Customer.where(name: 'john').fields(:foo).limit(10).sort(:foo).all
```

You can also pass the query around to perform other WHERE filtering on it before finally executing it with `all`, `first`, `each`, etc.

```
@johns_older_than_10 = filter_by_age(Customer.where(name: 'john')).all

def filter_by_age(query)
  query.where(age: { :$gt => 10 })
end
```

Note that you don't need to return `all` if you are looping with `each`.